# How can an app determine if its being launched from a terminated state due to Voip Push?

Tags: ios

[NOTE: This question is about VoiP pushes, not about ordinary pushes]
[NOTE2: The question is NOT about how to set up an app to receive Voip Pushes, read it properly what it is actually asking].

If the app is terminated and a Voip push arrives then within didFinishLaunchingWithOptions the options a nil.
(This can be contrasted against if an app is launched when the user taps on a local notification for example).

How does an app know its being launched due to the arrival of a VoIP push, as opposed to a push arriving while the app is already in the background?

Comment: Have you checked if `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` is called instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a delegate to the `PKPushRegistry` object you have created and specify it as a VOIP type:

```
let voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: nil)
voipRegistry.delegate = myPushDelegate
voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushType.voIP]
```

Your delegate will have to conform to the `PKPushRegistryDelegate` protocol.

Then, implement the `pushRegistry(_:didReceiveIncomingPushWith:for:completion:)` protocol function ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/2875784-pushregistry)) - this function will be called upon receiving a push (even if at the app was terminated earlier).

the function description:

> Notifies the delegate that a remote push has been received.
>
> the specified push type. Call the completion handler as soon as you
>   have finished processing the payload.This method is invoked when a push notification has been received for

please note thet the function: `pushRegistry(_:didReceiveIncomingPushWith:for:)` has been deprecated so don't be confused with the one I mentioned above.

More information about the `PKPushRegistryDelegate` protocol: [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate)

About the actual question, there is a work around for that - the idea is to create create a flag that will be destroyed when app will terminate but as soon as it wakes up it status will change - if the app woke up from background the flag status will be saved but if the app woke up after it was terminated the flag will hold the default value.

In the push's delegate class:

```
import PushKit
class PushDelegate: PKPushRegistryDelegate  {

    var flag = false

      func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType) {
            if flag {
                print("the app woke up from background")
            } else {
                print("the app was terminated")
                flag = true
            }
        }
}
```

In addition, in order to detect if the user launched the app (this is the only case that the app will be in active state) use the code below:

```
let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState

    if state == .background {

        // background
    }
    else if state == .active {

        // foreground
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think your read what the question is specifically about: "How does an app know its being launched due to the arrival of a VoIP push, as opposed to a push arriving while the app is already in the background?"   Did you read that very last sentence. That is what the question is asking, it is not asking how to know when a push arrived.

Comment: you want to distinguish between (only) 2  situations which both occurs due to push arrival: 1. the app is being launched (by arrival of push) 2. the app is already in background (and receives a push) ?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there is a way to distinguish these situations.

Comment: >>"create a flag that will be destroyed when app will terminate". But applicationWillTerminate is not guaranteed to be called in app situations, for example if user switch app to background at first, and after terminate the app, applicationWillTerminate will not be called.

Comment: Create a flag anywhere and it will be destroyed

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how this helps, exactly where would a flag get set, and exactly where would it be read.

Comment: you can (but not have to) set it in the push delegate as global var and then change it on the didReceiveIncomingPushWith - the idea is that this flag will hold its initial value only when the app first launch and after termination launch

Comment: I still don't see how that differentiates. If you update your answer with code examples and it works I'll accept the answer and award the bounty. At the moment I just don't see how its a solution to the question.

Comment: That does not answer the question. The question title is "How can an app determine if its being launched from a terminated state due to Voip push". The emphases here is the word "due".  The question re-iterates this saying: "*due to the arrival of a VoIP push*".  This is something that is possible to determine when the app is launched as a consequence of a local notification. Your solution only determines if a push is arriving for the first time after being launched, which is not the same as determining if the app launched *due* to the arrival of the push. The user could have launched the app.

Comment: You can determine if the user launched the app, you mentioned that yourself - I tested the solution and manage to determine if the app launched due to voip was terminated earlier or not good luck

Comment: You can't determine if the user launched the app as the launchOptions are empty in that situation same as they are if the app was launched from a voip Push. So you can't distinguish these two situations.

Comment: You can check that by checking if the app is active or background state - answer edited

Comment: when get pushkit the app automatically open