# Possible to use Voip push functionality only without voip messaging/calls?

Tags: ios

I want to use Voip push within my app as a more reliable alternative to silent push notifications and also have the ability for the app to be started from a terminated state on arrival of the push.

[Yes I do know the app would not be accepted in the app store if it doesn't additionally provide Voip functionality to the user and is just using Voip push instead of regular pushes].

But I'm wondering if there are any issues with doing so - for example if the app is terminated and a Voip push arrives I've noticed that after launching it the app does not them seem to terminate again afterwards. Which leads me to believe the OS might be expecting something like a completion() method to get called after for example the end of a Voip call? And if I don't call this completion() method might the OS eventually stop sending the pushes to the app as it thinks its not well behaved?

Comment: What makes you believe in that `completion()` facility ? Does your app lives in background longer than 30 seconds after push arrived ?

Comment: @sage444. I'm wondering if there should be, that's the question. My app doesn't usually run for longer than 30 seconds in the background but it could possibly if a download from a server is slow and takes a longtime to process the payload on a slow handset.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. So my app (real VOIP-client, min deployment target 9.0) doesn't call any kind of completion blocks/callbacks. But as you can see in Tim's answer it can vary from version of iOS.

Comment: Another point. Messing PushKit with another background execution mechanisms can be tricky and hard to maintain especially if you need to support several version of iOS.

Comment: @sage444 could you please elaborate. I'm only supporting >= iOS 10. And its only the push notifications from push kit I am using, nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I look at the [PKPushRegistryDelegate docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate), I notice that the method you need to implement to handle a VoIP push is:

```
optional func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void)
```

Note the last parameter is a `completion` block. The discussion for this method says:

> Call the completion handler as soon as you have finished processing the payload.

So yes, I suspect calling that completion handler is necessary to indicate to the PushKit framework that you're no longer working to process the push.

(There is an older variant of that delegate message without the `completion` parameter, but it was deprecated in iOS 11, which is a hint that some OS behavior may have changed and that the completion block now must be called.)

Comment: I was using  func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, forType type: PKPushType). I didn't notice there was an overload. So therefore I wonder why there are two variants and what the one without the completion is for.

Comment: The one without the overload was likely an older version of the same callback. The OS may have assumed that you'd do all your processing synchronously inside that method, so it could shut down your app as soon as that method returned, or it may have given you some fixed amount of time. Either way, the new `completion`-bearing variant will be more reliable moving forward, since the old one is formally deprecated.

Comment: Tim bounty can't be awarded for 24 hours.